# How to create a list for all unique elements in a column that share the same ID in another column?

Tags: r, list, aggregate, unique

I have a dataset `all_transcripts` in which I have one column `ConvID` and a column `name`:

```
>all_transcripts


ConvID  Name
    5   Guest
    5   Guest      
    5   Agent      
    5   Guest     
    5   Agent      
    6   Reception      
    6   Guest  
    6   Agent 
    6   Guest      
    6   Guest      
    7   Reception     
    7   Reception     
    7   Guest 
    7   Guest      
    7   Reception        
    8   Reception      
    8   Guest      
    8   Agent
```

I want to get the unique names per ConvID

My desired output looks like:

```
5 ['Guest','Agent']
6 ['Reception','Guest','Agent']
7 ['Reception','Guest']
8 ['Reception','Guest','Agent']
```

To do so, I tried the aggregate function as follows:

`aggregate(interactionId~name, all_transcripts, FUN= 'unique')`

But this does not work. How can I change my code so I get the desired output?

Comment: Is your desired output a list? If so, you might try `unstack(unique(dat), Name ~ ConvID)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `tidyverse` solution.

The difference here is that the nesting gives a list-column back as opposed to a character vector column. Depending on your needs this may or may not be better.

```
library(tidyverse, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

all_transcripts %>%
  nest(-ConvID) %>%  
  mutate(unique_names = map(data, ~ unique(.[, "Name", drop = TRUE]))) %>%
  select(-data)
#>   ConvID            unique_names
#> 1      5            Guest, Agent
#> 2      6 Reception, Guest, Agent
#> 3      7        Reception, Guest
#> 4      8 Reception, Guest, Agent
```

#### `data.table` solution

```
library(data.table)

setDT(all_transcripts)

all_transcripts[, .(unique_names = list(unique(Name))) , by = ConvID]
#>    ConvID          unique_names
#> 1:      5           Guest,Agent
#> 2:      6 Reception,Guest,Agent
#> 3:      7       Reception,Guest
#> 4:      8 Reception,Guest,Agent
```

#### data

```
all_transcripts <- structure(list(ConvID = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
                                             6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L), Name = c("Guest", "Guest", 
                                                                                           "Agent", "Guest", "Agent", "Reception", "Guest", "Agent", "Guest", 
                                                                                           "Guest", "Reception", "Reception", "Guest", "Guest", "Reception", 
                                                                                           "Reception", "Guest", "Agent")), .Names = c("ConvID", "Name"), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                        -18L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The `dplyr` solution provided works for me, but if you want to stick to `aggregate` you could do as follows:

```
df <- tribble(
~ConvID,  ~Name,
5,   "Guest",
5,   "Guest",      
5,   "Agent",      
5,   "Guest",     
5,   "Agent",      
6,   "Reception",      
6,   "Guest", 
6,   "Agent", 
6,   "Guest",     
6,   "Guest",      
7,   "Reception",    
7,   "Reception",     
7,   "Guest",
7,   "Guest", 
7,   "Reception",       
8,   "Reception",      
8,   "Guest",      
8,   "Agent"
)

unique_m <- function(x){
  paste(unique(x), collapse = ", ")
}

df2 <- aggregate(Name~ConvID, df, FUN= 'unique_m')

df2
#>   ConvID                    Name
#> 1      5            Guest, Agent
#> 2      6 Reception, Guest, Agent
#> 3      7        Reception, Guest
#> 4      8 Reception, Guest, Agent
```

You need to create a different `unique` function; otherwise, you will get a list-column in `df2`.